# Disabling animation when changing layer/view properties?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, calayer

I composed a kind of animation by adding several layers to a UIView. Those layers shall be set visible or invisible by a script.

The script is based on objects that implement a protocol:

```
// the general protocol for a step
@protocol ActionStep 
-(void) applyForTime:(int)playtime;
-(void) reset;
@end
```

an in a timer I iterate through the step objects:

```
NSEnumerator* enumerator = [ScriptObjects objectEnumerator];
id obj;

while ( obj = [enumerator nextObject] )
{
  id <ActionStep> step = obj;
  [step applyForTime:currentmilliseconds];
}
```

One script object is this object:

```
@interface LayerStep : NSObject <ActionStep> 
{
  int mTimeOffset;
  CGPoint mOffset;
  float mAlpha;
  LayerObject* mTheLayer;
  bool mPrepared;
}
-(id)initWithLayerObject: (LayerObject*) theLayer Milliseconds:(int) milliseconds     Offset:(CGPoint) offset Alpha:(float)alpha;

@end
```

and finally I implement the protocol in the layer:

```
-(void) applyForTime:(int)playtime
{
  if ( mPrepared )  // has the step already been executed?
  {
    if ( playtime >= mTimeOffset )
    {
      [mTheLayer setAlpha:mAlpha];     //   AssignedLayer.opacity = alpha;
      [mTheLayer setPosition:mOffset]; //   AssignedLayer.position = offset;
      mPrepared = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Applying the changes in the step results in a transition.

Is there a way to disable this transition? I am not using any CoreAnimation call at all right now, just the properties itself (see code).

Comment: I think we need to see a bit more code - for instance, how are you doing the transition? What do you mean by "just the properties" ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Changing one of a layer's "animatable" properties creates what Apple's docs calls an implicit animation.

To quote the Xcode docs on the subject:

> Core Animation’s implicit animation model assumes that all changes to
>   animatable layer properties should be gradual and asynchronous.
>   Dynamically animated scenes can be achieved without ever explicitly
>   animating layers. Changing the value of an animatable layer property
>   causes the layer to implicitly animate the change from the old value
>   to the new value. While an animation is in-flight, setting a new
>   target value causes the animation transition to the new target value
>   from its current state.

Under the covers, the system generates a CAAnimation that makes the change.

As the other poster said, you can use setAnimationDuration to make the animation happen in an instant, which has the effect of turning animations off. I suspect that the system still generates an animation however.

The official way to turn off implicit layer animations is to use

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions: YES];
//layer changes
[CATransaction commit];
```

### Edit:

In Swift 3, this code would look like this:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
//layer changes
CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: Yes, this looks more promising and more precise. I suspected something like that in the object properties itself, I still have to get used to the fact that objective-c and cocoa do not really work the OO way...

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap the code where you are making the change.

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0];

[thelayer setAlpha:0];

[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Thanks. This works fine. I just thought I could somehow circumvent the 'bloat' of using CA. But maybe I am wrong since actually CA is designed for this.

Comment: I am using this now and turn it into a feature. The animation time is now part of the init method, so I can show things AND move or fade them.