# Disable rotating animation when using CATransform3DRotate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, catransform3drotate

I'm trying to use `CATransform3DRotate` to rotate a UIView/UIImageView on screen but it displays some sort of rotation animation when I apply the transformation to the View. Is there any way that I can disable this and just get the final result without the intermediate effect?

Comment: You go through this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155641/disabling-animation-when-changing-layer-view-properties?rq=1

it might help for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions: YES];
// Your code here
[CATransaction commit];
```